# Tableau Maximum of a Sum

Tags: tableau-api

I am relatively new to Tableau and this problem has been a real head scratcher.

I have a database table with a similar layout to:

```
ID INT (Unique ID)
create_ts DateTime
```

What I want is a bar graph that is bucketed for each hour (0-23.) This was easy enough to accomplish with Tableau's Datepart function. But for the height of the bars, I want the maximum count(*) that happened during that hour on any given day. So for hour 1 (1 AM) I want to see the highest number of count(ID) with a create_ts in the 1 AM hour calculated by day of create_ts. Hopefully that makes sense. Basically looking for peak numbers.

I have looked into "Level of Detail" calculations for Tableau, but was unable to make this work. I am on Tableau v10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

Create calculated field `maxIDCount` having definition as below and use it as the vertical bar field.

```
{fixed[datepart_hour_field]: countd([ID])}
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem:)*

Comment: Hi! Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't behave the way I need it to. Doing this gives me the total number of IDs that have create_ts in each hour, it doesn't total it by day then give me the max. (Switching between SUM and MAX aggregation on the graph doesn't change the graph at all)

Comment: Hey, I actually modified this a little bit and got it to work. I used {include datepart("day", [create_ts]) : countd([id])

Comment: Great! Just be careful with `include` as it compute values using the specified dimensions in addition to whatever dimensions are in the view. For difference between `fixed` and `include` check [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html)